# how to insert dynamic row data form into mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I want to get the attendance from the student list into my database.

I have my newattinsert.php file here:

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <input type="date" name="attdate" id="attdate" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="attdate" id="attdate" class="form-control" min="1990-01-01" max="2030-12-31" required/>
          </div>

          <?php 

          if (! empty($_POST['classn'])) {
        $class = $_POST['classn'];                  
        //run the store proc
        $sql = "CALL addattlist('".$class."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if (! empty($result)) {?>
          <div class="row" style="width: 140%;">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Class Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>"><?php echo $row['studentname']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="classn" value="<?php echo $row[2] ?>"><?php echo $row['classname']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" id="absent" name="status" value="Absent">
                      <label for="status">Absent</label>
                      
                      <input type="radio" id="present" name="status" value="Present">
                      <label for="status">Present</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                } 
                ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <?php
        }
      }
      ?>

      <div class="group" href="attendanceinsert.php" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 5px;">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Submit Data</button> OR <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reset The Form</button>
      </div>
```

and my attedanceinsert.php file here:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



    
    $name= $_POST['. $row[1] .'];
    $classn= $_POST['. $row[2] .'];
    $status= $_POST['status'];
    $attdate= $_POST['attdate'];

    $sql = "CALL attendanceregister('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['classn']."','".$_POST['status']."','".$_POST['attdate']."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result){
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Attedance Recorded!';
        header('location: allatt.php');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Something went wrong!';
    } 

}
?>
```

the problem is, I only get the data of the last student in the list only and the radio button only allows me to choose one choice only. If I click on the radio button on the student no1, the data that get into my database is the data from the student no2. Any idea how to resolve this? I'm really desperate as this is the only problem that I'm stuck at right now.

[image]
[image]

ps: this is the stored procedure that I use

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addattlist`(IN `class` VARCHAR(20))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
SELECT studentid, student_name, classname 
FROM student
WHERE classname = class;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: I still can't figure out the solution. I'm open to any changes or anything that will make it work.

Comment: Why do you use stored procedure?

Comment: @Dharman to make it easier for me. is that a bad thing? I'm still new and exploring

Comment: Stored procedures usually make things much more difficult not easier. You should be using normal prepared statements.

Comment: I see. I'll change it to the normal statements. but still, will that resolve my problem?